# Regex to select/replace greater than symbol in spefic <tag>

Tags: regex, replace, match

Im trying to select all the less than (<) symbols between a specific `<tag>` to replace them.
I tried it for hours, but I cant get it work :/

Example:

```
<mytag>
   the number 1<2!
</mytag>
```

In this example I would like to select the < between 1 and 2...

Comment: You should include your attempts in your question. Also, if your data is in xml or html, it might be easier to use a proper parser.

Comment: Parsing XML with regular expressions is not a good idea.

Comment: You need to be more explicit with what you're searching for: do you want all the _<_ that only are found between two numbers?

Comment: Hey guys, thx so far for your replies. Its a very complicated situation. Im writing a plugin for a shopsystem that loads some pages by ajax. I want to take out the JS from the pages and put it in my header. Everythings works fine as long the JS doesnt contain any less than (<) symbol, because JS reconizes it as a tag opening. So I want to replace them and re-replace them when I insert it.

Comment: @PhilippWoe Do you have only `<` or is the issue also for `>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex like that maybe?

```
<(?=[^>\/]*<\/)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lT9bZ2).

Basically, this part `(?=[^>\/]*<\/)` ensures that the `<` is followed by a `<\` part without any `>` in between, so that the opening angled bracket in a tag won't match.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot so far. But I need a way to specify the parent element, because <mytag> wont be my root element..

Comment: You can specify it in the regex? Something like `(?=[^>\/]*<\/mytag)` ?

Comment: @PhilippWoe Yup! No problem :)